# Xamarin PCL to hold WCF client doesn't have HttpCookieContainerBindingElement

Tags: wcf, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin, portable-class-library

Basically, I'm writing an android application and an iOS Phone/Tablet application using Xamarin and I want to have all common code out in a PCL library. All was going fine until I got the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to set the CookieContainer. Please make sure the binding contains an HttpCookieContainerBindingElement.
```

On trying to add this `HttpCookieContainerBindingElement` to the binding, I discover that the class does not even exist. My PCL targets Xamarin.iOS, Xamarin.Android, .Net 4.5, and Silverlight 5.

This is a complete and total blocker for me now. Can any of you guys shed some light on this for me and show me a way forward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a solution, but there's a long thread on this topic on the Xamarin forums:
http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/2369/cookiecontainer-missing-in-6-2-1

Comment: Thanks Joe, that's basically my problem too. No further forward and no Xamarin guys have responded to my post on their forums.

Comment: Is there any chance you can use Web API for the service end of this application instead of WCF? I cut my teeth on web services with WCF, which at the time I thought was great. BUT then I started using MVC for writing web services, and then further started using Web API. I can say that I personally will always avoid WCF like the plague if I can help it. Web API (and even MVC) is so much more of a pleasure for writing web services. Decouple yourself from WCF and start using the Microsoft Portable HttpClient. Problem solved! :)

Comment: Actually yeah I could use either HttpClient or WebApi if hey are viable alternatives to WCF in a portable class library? I've not used them much if at all before so I'd need to find some resources to follow on them first. Do either of them generate the proxy or data transfer objects?

Comment: The concept of generated proxy classes doesn't apply when discussing WebAPI and HttpClient. You'll still have the concept of data transfer objects (DTOs), often just referred to as the model, but they won't be auto-created for you. Here's the NuGet for the portable HttpClient: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/. That's a cross-platform HttpClient. It's awesome. As for Web API, just create a new Web API project in Visual Studio and google for some tutorials.